# Crop the Detected area python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-segmentation

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from pytesseract import Output
import re
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

# noise removal
#this works on date
image = cv2.imread('1.Chase Bank_test.jpg')
result = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(result,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (40,1))
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)

# Remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,40))
remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)


date_list= []

d = pytesseract.image_to_data(thresh, output_type=Output.DICT)
#d = pytesseract.image_to_data(thresh)


keys = list(d.keys())

#date_pattern = '([\d]+\/[\d]+)'

#Regular expression to get date
date_pattern = '^(0[1-9]|[12]|[1-9]|3[02])/'
#amount= '((\d+)(\,)(\d+)(\.))+\d+'

description = ''

n_boxes = len(d['text']) # make the boxes around till the lenght text, put n_boxes in for loop
for i in range(n_boxes):
    if int(d['conf'][i]) > 10:
        if re.match(date_pattern, d['text'][i]):
            (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
            detect_img = cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 300, 0), 2) #dates works good with opening 




#logic for crop the detected date and append to date_list 
#for i in range(n_boxes):
#       crop_detect_img = detect_img[y:y+h+8, x:x+w+8]
#       test_list=(image_to_string((crop_detect_img)))
#       print(test_list)



#date_list.append(crop_detect_img)
#print(test_list)

crop_detect_img = detect_img[y:y+h+10, x:x+w+10]
crop_date_gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_detect_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


crop_date_thresh = cv2.threshold(crop_date_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]




date=(image_to_string((crop_date_thresh)))

print(date)



plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
plt.imshow(crop_date_thresh)

#plt.imshow()
plt.imshow(result)
#print(result)


contours = contours[1] if imutils.is_cv3() else contours[0]



ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
    cv2.rectangle(result,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,255,12),2)
    ROI_number += 1

plt.imshow('thresh', thresh)
```

**

> I can not figure out how crop to the detected dates from image in a
>   loop so I could pass the cropped images to tesseract OCR and append to
>   the date list. And please suggest me better OCR in python which is
>   free. SO i could generate better results. I am using OpenCV for my
>   problem with regix.

**
As you can see that its finding all the dates from the image and making boundary boxes

[image]

Comment: I cannot quite understand your question. You already have the dates in bounding boxes. What is it that you want to do now? Also, I see that for a few transactions there are dates side by side. Like 01/04 and 01/04 in the 4th transaction. Is this detection correct or do you only want to detect the dates under DATE column?

Comment: Your code seems to already crop each date bounding box. Could you further explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Raviteja Narra yes if it is possible it would be great.

Comment: There are many simple approaches for this. One of them being, get to the left top most roi in all the ROI's you detected. Now use the horizontal position of this to directly remove the 2nd occurrence in each row whenever applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the bounding box but does not know how to crop it? That's weird.

Anyway, I added the relevant code below. If it's not the right loop at least you now know how to crop an image in numpy:

```
n_boxes = len(d['text']) # make the boxes around till the lenght text, put n_boxes in for loop
for i in range(n_boxes):
    if int(d['conf'][i]) > 10:
        if re.match(date_pattern, d['text'][i]):
            (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])

            # crop ROI and dump to a file
            cropped = gray[y : y+h, x : x+w]
            imwrite('crop_' + str(i) + '.png', cropped)                

            detect_img = cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 300, 0), 2)
```

Comment: Great, then please click on the checkbox near the answer to select it as the official problem solver. As for your new problem, you are more than invited to create a new question on Stackoverflow and describe another problem. We keep one question per thread and this thread has been successfully solved. By doing this things you will help keep Stackoverflow organized and future visitors can find their answers more easily.

Comment: Its only cropping 01 part from the date. Its not showing all date format.Whats the solution.

Comment: Initially you left a comment that it worked. It sounds like you changed something in the code and now it's not working anymore. Anyway, my answer was mainly to show how to crop an image and save it to the disk. Where exactly in the code is the data that you need, only you know.

Comment: https://imgur.com/nM8CI4Q this is the image link can please take a look so you see the problem. Please

Comment: That screenshot seems to show the result of text extraction by an OCR library. You need to check the images that my answer writes to the disk and make sure they have more than `01` in them.

Comment: You gotta stop with those screenshots and use words to describe the problem. I hate to keep guessing stuff. Do this, share an example of the input image that you feed your application and I'll try to run this on my computer.

Comment: From here you can download the image https://imgur.com/sHgCYFp. The images which your code have cropped that is only with 01 that why i gave you link for cropped images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207167/discussion-between-karlphillip-and-cybermakarov).

Comment: rectify: cropped = gray[y : y+h, x : x+w] its like this and then it can cropped whole date format.